# using referenced id as a primary id

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Using composite primary key approach from sql database, is this a valid or general practice for nosql databases?

For instance

**Example of dept collection.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae"),
    "name" : "Sales"
}
```

**Example of employee_dept collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae"), // $dept._id
    "employee_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0af")
}
```

---

or should I leave the _id alone as below?

**Example of dept collection.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae"),
    "name" : "Sales"
}
```

**Example of employee_dept collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5411be6cd7524f36a7933f"),
    "dept_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae"),
    "employee_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0af")
}
```

Comment: SQL databases are specifically designed to facilitate and enforce relationships like this. Is there a reason you are not using a SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in your case you might want to have a look how you should **design your schema** in MongoDB.

In classic SQL databases, you may always try to **normalize** your data, separating tables and makes relations.

In MongoDB the idea would be to **denormalize** and group documents that have relations into one.

For example, in your case, instead of having a `dept` collection and an `employee_dept`, you may want to have a single `employee` collection (or the other way around) that contains a `debt` field.

```
employee collection
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5411be6cd7524f36a7933f"),
    "firstname" : "John",
    "lastname" : "Doe",
    "dept" : {
        "name" : "Sales"
    }
}
```

Of course it may not fit exactly your use case since I don't have the full picture, but it may help you going forward in the right direction.

Comment: I see, so the idea is to denormalize, but let's say dept has tons of information, in that case I've to separate it out in a different collection, when this is the case, would you use `_id` as a reference as per my first example?

Comment: It depends. If `dept` is linked to a lot of employees, then you could store it in a different collection and reference it through its id. For exemple adding `dept : ObjectId()` in the employee document.

You could also have a partial view of a dept in the employee document. `dept : { name: "Sales", some_field: "", _id: ObjectId() }`. The `_id` here references the dept collection, which contains more fields. In this case you store in the employee collection the fields of `dept` that you query at the same time as an employee. Those fields are duplicated from the `dept` collection.